# trying to check the value in a button using javascript immediately the loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting the check the value in a button using a javascript onload function on getting the value of the button I am performing a check and if the check is true let it disable a preview button using its id. This is the javascript snippet

```
window.onload = function() {  

    //var text = $(".badge").text();
    var totalCheck = document.getElementById('totalcheck').value;
    alert("before check");
    if(totalCheck == "0.0"){
        alert(totalCheck);

        $('#disbtn').on('click',function() {
            $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        });

        }

  }
```

This is the button I am checking immediately the window loads

```
<button id="totalcheck" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                   Total <span id="price" class="badge">0.00</span>
                            </button>
```

This is the button I am attempting to disable if the check is true

```
<button id="disbtn" class="one btn btn-primary" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     Preview </button>
```

the interesting thing is that the alert never pops up even before the check. Please what could be wrong

Comment: If there is no alert even before `if`, it means that you didn't register onload handler properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Reason for not working?***

> 1. You are called the wrong `element` for matching with `if condition` . `0.00` is not a button value .its `span` text .so button
>      value is `null` so always return false in if
> 2. And if condition matching also  wrong .The innerTEXT is `0.00` but you are matching `0.0` so it always false.

so try like this

`var totalCheck = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;`

```js
function start() {
//var text = $(".badge").text();
  var totalCheck = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
  alert("before check "+ totalCheck);
  if (totalCheck.trim() == "0.00") {
    alert(totalCheck);

    $('#disbtn').on('click', function() {
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    });

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="start()">
<button id="totalcheck" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                   Total <span id="price" class="badge">0.00</span>
                            </button>


<button id="disbtn" class="one btn btn-primary" type="button">
       
                     Preview </button>
                     </body>
```

Comment: @parker see my updated answer.. which alert not showing.first one or second one ? which browser you are using ?

Comment: also, onload the preview is not disabled. and if total changes to any value let it be enabled

Comment: i think its a onload problem.try with my updated answer.i added with onload on `body`

Answer (score 0):

You have to take 'price' instead of 'totalcheck' to get your totalcheck,

```
         var totalCheck = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value Total is contained inside your span with ID "**price**".
Use **innerHTML** in place of value, since span does not support the property value.

```
var totalCheck = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
```